# what is the lim of $\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty }{ \frac { { 2 }^{ n }! }{ { 2 }^{ n! } } } $ and why?

Tags: limits

I don't know how to find this limit: $$\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { { 2 }^{ n }! }{ { 2 }^{ n! } }  } $$ I tried to something like:$ \frac { { 2 }^{ n } }{ 2 } \cdot \frac { { 2 }^{ n }-1 }{ 2 } \cdot \frac { { 2 }^{ n }-2 }{ 2 } \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \frac { 2\cdot 1 }{ 2 } $ but I don't know what to do next..

Comment: Notice that $2^n >n$ for natural $n$. Therefore, $(2^n)!>n!$. Try to use that direction to rewrite that multiplication expansion.

Comment: @NoySoffer That inequality doesn't help here.

Comment: What you've written here isn't the quantity you're interested in, however. You have $2^n$ terms multiplied in the numerator and yet you need $n!$ copies of $2$ in the denominator. Of course, $n!>2^n$ when $n\ge 4$.

Comment: how do i show that $n2^n-n! \to -\infty.$ ? someone?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\frac{2^n!}{2^{n!}} \le \frac{(2^n)^{2^n}}{2^{n!}} = 2^{n2^n-n!}$$

Comment: can you help some more pls? what i do from ${ 2 }^{ n{ 2 }^{ n }-n! }$ ?

Comment: You want to show $n2^n-n! \to -\infty.$

Comment: i got ${ \left( { \frac { { 2 }^{ { 2 }^{ n } } }{ { 2 }^{ \left( n-1 \right) ! } }  } \right)  }^{ n }$ now how i find the limit of this?

Comment: ok how do i show that n2^n-n! $\rightarrow -\infty $ ?

Comment: $n2^n-n!=n!\left(\frac{2^{n-1}}{3\cdot4\ldots(n-2)(n-1)}-1\right)$.

Comment: tnx nicolas, but i don't understand why $n2^n-n!=n!\left(\frac{2^{n-1}}{3\cdot4\ldots(n-2)(n-1)}-1\right)$ can you explain pls?

Comment: @AlonBerman Just put $n!$ in factor : the first term in parenthesis is $n2^n$ divided by $n!$. You can find the limit by showing that the precedent term tends to zero as $n\to+\infty$.

Comment: tnx!!! now why $n!\left( \frac { 2^{ n-1 } }{ 3\cdot 4(n-2)(n-1) } -1 \right) \rightarrow -\infty $ ?

Comment: @AlonBerman I do not believe that you will learn something if I tell you the answer. You should rather to show it by yourself. I can help you to do this : take $n>100$ to fix the idea ; then write $\frac{2^{n-1}}{3\cdot4\ldots(n-1)}=4\frac{2^{n-3}}{3\cdot4\ldots(n-1)}=4\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{2}{4}\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{2}{n-2}\frac{2}{n-1}<4\frac{2}{n-1}$.